# Obtaining a Return Value - AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

With the code snippet below, I am returning a value in AJAX, then checking the return value.  The problem that I am experiencing is that it returns "undefined".

```
function LoadUserControl() {
        var i;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Form.aspx/Load",
            data: "",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (r) {
                alert(r.d);// I get values
                var data = $.parseJSON(r.d);
                var ProjectID = data.ProjectID;
                alert(ProjectID );//undefined
                for (i = 0; i < r.d.length; i++) {
                    paramList = "{'FieldTypeName':'" + data.FieldTypeName + "'}";
                    if (paramList == "TextBox") {
                        alert();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: Can you show ur json that is being returned?

Comment: Instead of displaying the `r.d` can you just display the `r` in the console.log

Comment: @Tushar Gupta  [{"ProjectID":10,"SupportID":20}]

Comment: could you post your aspx code, which is returning the above json.

Comment: System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
             public static string Load()
             {
    
                 string ProjectID = "10";
                 Client Control = new Client();
                 DataSet dsField = Control.GetField(Int32.Parse(ProjectID));
    
                 string sReturn = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dsField.Tables[0]).ToString();
    
                 return sReturn;
    
    
             }